# Parse XML with incresing tag values using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm using some api which returns the list of transactions done by the user in XML format. This is how it looks like.

```
<Response>
<Status>00</Status>
<STMT>
   <T0>
      <ID>25624</ID>
      <DATE>30 JUNE 2014</DATE>
       <Amount>1500</Amount>
   </T0>
   <T1>
      <ID>11495</ID>
      <DATE>29 JUNE 2014</DATE>
       <Amount>1000</Amount>
   </T1>
   <T2>
      ----
      ----
      ---- 
</STMT>
<Bal>55</Bal>
</Response>
```

Now, how do we get those values inside `STMT` tags? I tried this, but didn't work.

```
$result=simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$i='0';
$tx ='T'.$i;
while ($result->STMT->$tx) {
    $result->STMT->$tx->ID;
    $tx='T'.strval(intval($i++));
}
```

Please help.

Comment: "but didin't work" does not qualify as a concrete question. You need to at least make more clear what didn't work. What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? Are you getting any errors? etc. pp. (just writing this because your code does not look that far off, I'd guess it actually works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is just straightforward. Do something like this:

```
$xml_string = '<Response><Status>00</Status><STMT> <T0> <ID>25624</ID> <DATE>30 JUNE 2014</DATE> <Amount>1500</Amount> </T0> <T1> <ID>11495</ID> <DATE>29 JUNE 2014</DATE> <Amount>1000</Amount> </T1> <T2> <ID>11496</ID> <DATE>28 JUNE 2014</DATE> <Amount>500</Amount> </T2></STMT><Bal>55</Bal></Response>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$stmt = $xml->STMT;
$stmt = json_decode(json_encode($stmt), true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($stmt);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [T0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 25624
            [DATE] => 30 JUNE 2014
            [Amount] => 1500
        )

    [T1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 11495
            [DATE] => 29 JUNE 2014
            [Amount] => 1000
        )

    [T2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 11496
            [DATE] => 28 JUNE 2014
            [Amount] => 500
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. You didn't echo the result...

```
echo $result->STMT->$tx->ID . "\n";
```

Also, `$i++` should be changed to `++$i`.